# why do I get 'key error' after groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I a m working on [this](https://www.tableau.com/covid-19-coronavirus-data-resources) Data Set
I want to get cumulative confirmed cases so I filtered by confirmed cases, grouped by Date and aggregated by sum.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
covid_tab=pd.read_csv('datasets/COVID-19 Cases.csv')

covid_tab['Date']=pd.to_datetime(covid_tab['Date'])
covid_tab.groupby(["Country_Region","Case_Type"]).agg({'Cases':'max'}).head()
cumulative_cases=covid_tab[covid_tab['Case_Type']=='Confirmed'].groupby('Date').agg({'Cases': 'sum'})
cumulative_cases.head()
```

I get something like this

[image: what i get]

but if I try to access the Date column I get a Key error, or if I try to print the column names I only get 'Cases' printed

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Date is set as an index after the groupby method. You can use reset_index() to turn it into a column

```
covid_tab[covid_tab['Case_Type']=='Confirmed'].groupby('Date').agg({'Cases': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```